# Abbreviate Sentence in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function to abbreviate words in a sentence, where there are 4 or more characters in a word. So "elephant-rides are really fun!" becomes "E6t-r3s are r4y fun!".

I managed to get up to where I abbreviated all the words, but I can't figure out three things.

1. My code requires that the string ends with a space. How to re-organise it so it doesn't have to end with a space for it to work?
2. My code doesn't work properly for words that are 3 or less characters - these are not to be abbreviated (I tried an else if statement after the if statement and it confused me)
3. It doesn't account for commas, semi-colons or other punctuation. Is there a way to do this without stuffing the if condition with a bunch of === statements?

Edit: I would also be interested in a non RegEx answer (although the ones that have been posted have been helpful) as I'm new to programming and am still trying to figure loops out.

```js
function abbrv(str) {
 var word=""
  var newStr=""
  var counter= 0
  var oldCounter= 0 
       for (var i=0; i<str.length; i+=1){
          counter+= 1
          word+= str[i]
            if(str[i]===" "||str[i]==="-"){
             newStr += word[oldCounter]+(counter-(oldCounter+3)).toString()+word[counter-2]+str[i]
             oldCounter= counter
            }
       }
 console.log(newStr)
}

abbrv("Elephant-rides are really fun ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at each character and check for a non letter and reset the counter. If a letter is found, check the count and append if the count is zero.

```js
function abbrv(str) {
    var newStr = "",
        count = 0,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] === " " || str[i] === "-") {
            if (count > 0) {
                newStr += count > 3 ? count - 2 : str[i - 2];
                newStr += str[i - 1];
            }
            newStr += str[i];
            count = 0;
            continue;
        }
        if (count === 0) {
            newStr += str[i];
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        newStr += count > 3 ? count - 2 : str[i - 2];
        newStr += str[i - 1];
    }
    return newStr;
}

console.log(abbrv("Elephant-rides are really funy"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or you could use a regular expression for replacing the words with the abbreviation.

```js
function abbrv(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w{4,}/g, function (s) {
        var l = s.length;
        return s[0] + (l - 2) + s[l - 1];
    });
}

console.log(abbrv("Elephant-rides are really fun"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Using `replace` and the regex for long words is a nice addition! Might have been better to have kept your previous post and commented this as a suggestion under my answer though... There were 2 versatile answers before, now yours is just a patched version of mine...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `\b` regex to match words:

```js
function abbrWord(word) {
  if (word.length <= 3) return word; // This also filters out ", " or "-"
  
  return word[0] + 
    (word.length - 2) + 
    word[word.length - 1];
}

function abbrv(str) {
  return str.split(/\b/)   // Create an array of words and word boundaries
    .map(abbrWord)         // for each item in the array, replace with abbr.
    .join("");             // join items together to form a string
  
}

console.log(abbrv("Elephant-rides are really fun"))
```

Notes:

- It's nice to have your *word-abbreviation* and *sentence-splitting* logic separated. This makes it easy to change one of the two without influencing the other
- With regex, there are many ways to quickly search for certain patterns of characters. Look in to `match` and `test` as well.

Comment: Oh wow thanks. I know practically nothing about RegEx, but I get this. Thanks for the additional pointers too.

Comment: You're welcome. The answer below by Nina streamlines the `split`, `map`, `join` using `replace`. Might be nice to incorporate that as well!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 'Elephant-rides are really fun ';

const result = input.split(/\W+/).filter(x => x).map(x => x.length < 4 ? x : x[0] + (x.length - 2) + x[x.length-1]);

console.log(result);
```